Слитно или раздельно в данном предложении употребляется слово "необязательный"?

В вузе сообщили о том, что некоторые строки форм бланков переведут из
разряда обязательных к заполнению в разряд не( )обязательных.


В вузе сообщили о том, что некоторые строки форм бланков переведут из разряда обязательных к заполнению в разряд необязательных.

